# Problem executing bash file

Tags: php, bash, shell

HI there!

I've run into some problem while learning to combine .sh files and PHP. I've create a file test.sh and in that file I call a PHP file called test.php.

If I double click on the .sh file then it runs perfectly but when I try to run it from the terminal I get "command not found". I'm in the exact folder as my .sh file but it wont work. Here's my test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIB=${0/%cli/}
exec php -q ${LIB}test.php one two three
exit;
```

When I doubleclick on the test.sh file then it returns the argv array like it suppost to. But why can't I run it from terminal?

Comment: How are you executing the shell script? You're probably calling it without pre-pending the path (something like ./)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `./filename.sh`

no matter if your are in the same folder or not, without giving ./ the system is searching the path variable. (/bin/, /usr/bin and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Is execute bit enabled?

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your environment is different when launching from the Terminal and when launching via a double-click. Try executing `which php` and `echo $PATH` from the Terminal to see what the deal is.

**EDIT 1**
As others have noted, if your "command not found" is referring to the shell script and not php, then you probably forgot to include the "./" before the name of the script (i.e. `./test.sh`). Also, don't forget to make it executable by invoking `chmod a+x test.sh`. The reason for this is that PATH does not include the current directory (i.e. "."), because doing so would be a security risk (e.g. folders with a ton of files in them including a fake "ssh" which could then intercept your password or the like).

**EDIT 2**
Also, I don't know about you, but `${0/%cli/}` is evaluating to `-bash` from within my Terminal. Are you sure that's what you wanted it to expand to? Perhaps you should specify the exact filename.

Answer (score 0):

Your $PATH variable may not include '.' - so the shell may not be able to find the command to run.

As others have said, sh ./file.sh will work...

Comment: PATH should not include ".", as that is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run it with sh (or bash, if sh on your machine isn't bash and the script uses bashims)

```
sh filename.sh
bash filename.sh
```

This will work whether or not the file is executable or in $PATH