# Bash File Script- PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, xen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem executing bash file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559245/problem-executing-bash-file)

I have created a bash file script and stored in some directory. 
Now I need to create a php script to execute this bash script so anyone can help me!!

Comment: Better dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168179/allowing-php-to-execute-a-bash-script-with-root-permissions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884390/cant-run-shell-script-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
exec('/path/to/that/bash/file');
```

Answer (score 1):

Function exec gets executes script and with additional parameter it collects output from script.

```
$output = '';
exec("/path/to/your/bash/script.sh", &$output);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec or exec can help you.
Read more at http://us.php.net/exec